# Issue with scrolling in smaller devices

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-grid

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC. Bootstrap is used for the UI. I have the below HTML in my layout view.

```
<body>
    @*Header*@
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @*<li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>*@
                    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu3</a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
                © 2017 xxxxxxxxxx             
            </p>

            <a class="navbar-btn btn-default btn pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>&nbsp;<strong>This is test</strong> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try to see the page in smaller devices (iPhone5/6) etc, I see that the contents from my content page grows below the sticky footer and hence not getting displayed. But, the display is fine in bigger devices. How can I add a scrollbar, or make the content scrollable when viewed in smaller devices?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed navbars overlap main content by default. To avoid this you need to add margins to your content block. According to bootstrap 3 it will look like this:

```
<div class="page-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

And then in your styles file:

```
.page-content {
    maring: 50px 0;
}
```